# How to automatically place XAML attributes on next line?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Visual Studio (for Mac) used to place XAML attributes on the next line when auto-formatting, but ever since a recent update (not sure which one), it now places them all on one line when auto-formatting, which is super annoying because I much prefer the previous way. I can't seem to figure out how to change it back. I did not touch any settings at all, and I can't seem to find any settings that will fix this for me.

I have looked at [Microsoft's Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-xaml-formatting?view=vs-2019), which shows a setting that looks like it would solve this issue for me:

> **Position each attribute on a separate line**
>
> Each attribute occupies its own line, which is useful when many attributes are present.
>
> ```
> XAML
>
> <Button
> Height="23"
> Name="button1"
> Width="75">Hello</Button>
> ```

The issue with this is that I cannot find this setting. The page says to go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **XAML** > **Formatting**, but I do not see **Options** under **Tools**, which lead me to [another page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/editor-behavior?view=vsmac-2019) that says to go to **Preference** > **Text Editor** > **Behavior**, but neither this tab nor its child **XAML** has any settings that would put attributes on the next line.

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, it would be much appreciated. I would prefer a solution that would allow me to customize how the auto-formatting (control + i) works rather than downloading an extension where I need to use a console command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this having the same issue, I finally figured it out from poking around some more in the settings.

Go to **Preferences** > **Source Code** > **Code Formatting** > **XML document** > **XML Format** and then check the 'Attributes on new line' box.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools`➝ `Options` ➝ `Text Editor` ➝ `XAML` ➝ `Formatting` ➝ `Spacing`.

Then in the "Attribute Spacing" group, choose "Position each attribute on a separate line."
If you want the first attribute to start from the next line, uncheck the "Position first attribute on same line as start tag" checkbox.

[image]

*Note: this approach is validated on Visual Studio 2019.*

---

For more information, check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-xaml-formatting?view=vs-2019).

Comment: How to do it with .editorconfig?